# What are some good algorithms for numerical integration for a physics engine?

Tags: c++, physics-engine

I have been looking around online for a while now for methods of integration for a physics engine I am trying to code for fun (gotta love the nerdiness there :P). I have found Euler's method, RK4, and Verlet (as well as the time corrected version). I have also been trying to come up with some of my own methods. I was wondering if you knew of any others that you found intuitive or helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for all of your help so far. As for clarification: perhaps I do mean numeric integration. Surprisingly, in all my research, I have not found so much as the technical NAME for what I am trying to do! Perhaps describing my specific problem will make my question more clear. Lets say I want to simulate a ball moving through a circular (or spherical once I implement 3d) gravitational field. This ball will encounter force vectors which can be used to calculate a corresponding acceleration vector for the point the ball is at on that specific tick. From your physics class, you know that velocity = acceleration * time but my problem is that the ball is technically on that point for only an instant, represented mathematically in calculus by dt. Obviously, I cannot use an infinitesimally small number in C++ so I must approximate the solution using methods of instantaneous integration (a term I heard in some reading but I could be completely wrong about) or what you think is called numerical integration (you are probably right so I changed the title).

Here is my (successful) attempt at implementing the Euler method of numerical integration:

```
    //For console output. Note: I know I could just put "using namespace std;" but I hate doing that.
    #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::system;
    using std::endl;

    //Program entry
    int main (void)
    {
        //Variable decleration;
        double time = 0;
        double position = 0;
        double velocity = 0;
        double acceleration = 2;
        double dt = 0.000001; //Here is the "instantanious" change in time I was talking about.
        double count = 0; //I use count to make sure I am only displaying the data at whole numbers.

        //Each irritation of this loop is one tick
        while (true)
        {

            //This next bit is a simplified form of Euler's method. It is what I want to "upgrade"
            velocity += acceleration * dt;
            position += velocity * dt;

            if (count == 1/dt) //"count == 1/dt" will only return true if time is a whole number.
            {

                //Simple output to console
                cout << "Time: " << time << endl;
                cout << "Position: " << position << endl;
                cout << "------------------" << endl;
                system ("pause");

                count = 0; //To reset the counter.

            }

            //Update the counters "count" and "time"
            count++;
            time += dt;

        }
        return 1; //Program exit
    }
```

Because the acceleration is constant and this differential is actually solvable (why I am using it to test, the solution is position = time ^ 2, this is fairly accurate but if you make it a bit more complicated by, for example, making the acceleration change over time, the algorithm loses accuracy extremely rapidly. Again, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "instantaneous integration"? Do you mean "numeric integration?"

Comment: I think, the author means "numeric integration of ordinary differential equations". Runge-Kutta method is pretty good.

Comment: @AnalyticalInsanity Your Newton's 2nd law can be solved analytically. It's simply `m * d^2x/dt^2 = constant`. Solution is obtained by direct integration twice and the result is familiar `x = (1/2)*a*t^2 + v0*t + x0`... By the way, I like you comment: _//Each irritation of this loop is one tick_

Comment: You are not allowed to vandalize your own posts. Do not do this again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a second order differential equation (ODE) x''=f(x,x',t). x can be a vector and x' and x'' are the first and the second derivative with respect to the time. In your case x is the position, x' is the velocity and x'' is the acceleration. Usually one transforms this second order ODE into a first ODE by introducing X=x,Y=x' and you obtain

X'=Y
Y'=f(X,Y)

Then you can use the classical schemes for solving ODEs like Runge-Kutta, Dormand-Prince, Adams-Bashforth, ...

Many of these methods are implemented in [odeint](http://www.odeint.com) which is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different algorithms for numerically integrating ODEs.  See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations) for an overview.  Which algorithms are suitable depends strongly on the properties of the ODE you are trying to solve.  The Euler method rarely performs well, in that you often need a very small step size to achieve a good approximation to the solution (but this is very easy to implement, so might be good for a first try).  There are variations like the backward Euler method which can do a little better.

The [Runge-Kutta methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_methods) are a broad class of methods, which include the Euler method.  As you increase the order of the method, you generally require fewer time steps to achieve the same accuracy, but performing the calculations at each time step becomes increasingly expensive - RK4 is used very often as it tends to strike a good balance.

In practice, [adaptive step size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_stepsize) techniques are generally used to control the time step to achieve a desired accuracy.

There are many existing implementations of ODE solvers, which people have put a lot of work in to - while it is good that you are interested in knowing how they work, these solvers can get pretty complicated, so if you aren't satisfied with the results you get from your own attempts, it might be a better idea to look into existing routines, such as [those in the GNU Scientific Library.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html)